# How do I make a tmpfs mountpoint persistent across reboots?

Tags: mysql, tmpfs

If I create a ram disk on cent os using tmpfs will it go away on restart? I know the data will go away (I would assume), but will it still survive a reboot?

I am going to allocate a ram disk for use on mysql /tmp directory I just want to make sure it will work after reboot. (I don't have another server to try it on)

Comment: What do you mean by making sure it will work? Do you want the `/tmp` directory to be tmpfs again (that is easily done with an entry in /etc/fstab and starting mysql after mounting). But the **contents** mysql put there will be gone.

Answer (score 7):

The data on a [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) *(Temporary Filesystem)* will not persist across reboots.

If you only care to preserve the mountpoint, that will be dictated by your `/etc/fstab` definition.